# Two-body correlation function computation

Tags: entropy, correlation-functions, molecular-dynamics

TL;DR Summary: How to compute correlation function from MD data?

I'm studying how to compute excess entropy in molecular dynamics (MD). I've found it is needed to compute the two-body correlation function (neglecting high-order terms), the details can be found, for example, in [this article](https://dx.doi.org/10.1039/C6CP00720A).

So the definition of correlation function (CF for short) is
$$C(t,\vec r, t',\vec r')=\langle X(t,\vec r)Y(t', \vec r')\rangle$$
where angle brackets mean averaging.

First question: is the averaging performed by time or ensemble (by all the atoms in the system)?

Second: for computing the CF, do I need to compute it in the stationary process? I mean, do I need to simulate a steady-state system in MD (probably to perform time-averaging) or can CF be found from one time point (using atom coordinates and velocities in a specific time moment)?

Third: If, for example, I want to compute CF for relative distance $\vec r=\vec r_2-\vec r_1$, where $\vec r_1, \vec r_2$  are the absolute positions of two atoms, what will be $X$ and $Y$?

I'm sorry if I've written something unclear, I'm always ready to clarify the question, and I'd be happy for any help.

P.S. My goal is to calculate the free Gibbs energy of bunch of atoms via computing entropy or configuration integral (partition function).

Comment: What is the dynamics of your bunch of atoms? You do not need correlation functions at all if it is purely roto-vibrational dynamics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the equation in words : To find $C(r, t, r^{\prime}, t^{\prime})$ you take some frame at time $t$, go to position $r$, and evaluate your property $X(r, t)$, then you shift the frame in your trajectory by the time $t^{\prime}$, shift the position by the vector $r^{\prime}$, and evaluate your property $Y(r^{\prime}, t^{\prime})$, and then you calculate the product. You have to do this for all times $t$ and all time shifts $t^{\prime}$, all positions $r$ and all position shifts $r^{\prime}$. Note that in practice (for unbounded systems with periodic boundaries) the two-correlation only depends on the differences and thus you need two iterations (time and position shifts) rather than four. Unless you have some confinement then you expect of course some gradients in the density or current fields.

For your second question, this depends on what you like to analyze. If you are looking at the response of your system to some applied force, then you can calculate for example the density or current fields in the non-equilibrium trajectory. If you like to extract radial distributions or time-correlation functions, then it is clearly easier to consider equilibrium data.